# How to add search option for the queries we create in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Hi Team I am new to log stash and Elastic search.

In my log stash, I get lot of logs, few examples are 
celery-logs, nginx-logs, and management-logs

I have created Queries like category==celery-logs, category==nginx-logs and category==mgmt-logs

Created three panels attaching each specific query to all three, under every category there are multiple log levels like info, error, waring..etc

How can I create a search pattern which is individual to each panel?

I have tried creating filters, however filters are applicable to entire dashboard, please suggest me on how to create specific filters confined to panels.

Comment: With kibana 3 you can select multiple queries for a panel and apply them... I don't think you can do what you want with the current version of Kibana 4.

Comment: In Kibana4, you define the query with the visualization ("panel"), so each one can have a different query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me rephrase the question, how can I apply filter to a specific Panel instead of all

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create visualizations which are general to all categories and then have a Dashboard for each category. Dashboards can have a filter associated that they will remember. That way you reuse your visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create and save 3 visualizations, each one with a different filter. then each visuzlization will only display its filtered data.

Then you can put all 3 visualizations in a single dashboard. The dashboard query and filters can be empty (which will match_all) and still those 3 filters would be taken into account in the visualizations.